# Finding previous quarter null and fill with the previous quarter Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, logic

My actual table is like this

```
user_id  date_at          quarter    type_class
123     2022-01-13 8:30:25   1       beginner
123     2022-02-13 7:29:25   1       beginner to mid
123     2022-04-26 17:30:59  2       mid
123     2022-12-15 12:30:33  4       expert
```

My expected value is seems like this, i still confused

1. how to fill the type_class per quarter with the previous quarter(in quarter 3 the data is null, fill it with the previous quarter result)
2. how to only took the latest class in quarter(quarter 1 only took 'beginner to mid')

```
user_id  quarter  type_class
123      1        beginner to mid
123      2        mid
123      3        mid
123      4        expert
```

My current query

```
WITH class0 AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        quarter(start_at) as quarters,
        type_class,
        date_at,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM start_at) ORDER BY start_at DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM
        class
    WHERE
        DATE(date_at) BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
)

SELECT
    user_id,
    quarters,
    type_class,
FROM
    class0
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
GROUP BY ALL
```

Update current result

```
user_id  quarter  type_class
123      1        beginner to mid
123      2        mid
123      4        expert
```

But it still can't define if one of quarter is null, and took the latest value of quarter.

I appreciate all of your help. Thank you!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: Hi - so what are the rules/logic for converting the table you have to the table you want? At the moment it’s not obvious what any of your columns actually mean or why any of the columns in your second table are populated with the values you’re showing

Comment: Hi, sorry i just finished editing the question and also show my current query. So, i have a case ideally type_class always appear every month. But we have some issue some of month the type_class is null, and we want to know the latest class by quarterly. I want to show the latest type_class each quarter. For example user A latest update type_class is January and February then the latest quarter(Q1) type_class in February.

 if the type_class in the quarter(3 months is null) then show the previous quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the missing quarters, you need to perform a `CROSS JOIN` by quarters 1, 2, 3, and 4, to ensure that all quarters are included in the result set for each 'user_id' :

```
with class as (
  select  123  as user_id, '2022-01-13 8:30:25'::date as date_at, 'beginner' as type_class union all
  select  123,  '2022-02-13 7:29:25',  'beginner to mid' union all
  select  123,  '2022-04-26 17:30:59', 'mid' union all
  select  123,  '2022-12-15 12:30:33', 'expert' 
),
cte as (
  select user_id, date_at, quarter(date_at) as quarter, type_class, 
         row_number() over (partition by user_id, quarter(date_at) order by date_at desc) as rn
  from class
),
cte2 as (
  select q.value, c.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id, q.value order by quarter desc) as rn_quarter
  from cte c 
  cross join table(flatten([1,2,3,4])) q
  where rn = 1 and q.value >= quarter
)
select user_id, value as quarter, type_class
from cte2
where rn_quarter = 1;
```

Results :

```
USER_ID QUARTER TYPE_CLASS
123     1       beginner to mid
123     2       mid
123     3       mid
123     4       expert
```

Answer (score 1):

SelVazi's answer is really nice.

as quick rewrite to use QUALIFY to apply the filter inside the two CTE's makes it more clean what is wanted, at the next layer, it also allows to drop a CTE as the code does not have to drop the row_number columns, as they are just used for the ranking:

```
with class(user_id, date_at, type_class) as (
  select * from values 
      (123, '2022-01-13 8:30:25'::date, 'beginner'),
      (123, '2022-02-13 7:29:25'::date, 'beginner to mid'),
      (123, '2022-04-26 17:30:59'::date, 'mid'),
      (123, '2022-12-15 12:30:33'::date, 'expert')
),
cte as (
  select 
    user_id, 
    date_at, 
    quarter(date_at) as quarter, 
    type_class
  from class
  qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id, quarter order by date_at desc) = 1
)
select
    c.user_id,
    value as quarter,
    type_class
from cte as c 
cross join table(flatten([1,2,3,4])) as q
where q.value >= c.quarter
qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id, q.value order by quarter desc) = 1
order by 1,2;
```

[image]

the cross join can be an explicit set of values also:

```
cross join values (1),(2),(3),(4) as q(value)
```

which allows for the `q.value` to be a better value than the default naming provided by the FLATTAN function.

the first row_number could be dropped,

```
qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id, quarter order by date_at desc) = 1
```

because it is filtering out all but the last per quarter, which the later filter also effectively does, but I actually like it, because on larger datasets (many dates, and/or users), it will make the open ended join faster. So it's not needed per say, but seems wise to leave in.

at which point the important SQL just becomes:

```
with class(user_id, date_at, type_class) as (
  select * from values 
      (123, '2022-01-13 8:30:25'::date, 'beginner'),
      (123, '2022-02-13 7:29:25'::date, 'beginner to mid'),
      (123, '2022-04-26 17:30:59'::date, 'mid'),
      (123, '2022-12-15 12:30:33'::date, 'expert')
)
select
    c.user_id,
    value as quarter,
    type_class
from class as c 
cross join values (1),(2),(3),(4) as q(value)
where q.value >= quarter(c.date_at)
qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id, q.value order by c.date_at desc) = 1
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir! I also have tried this. Thank you!